# Hybrid Mobile Community App Setup

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

Trying to setup a hybrid_remote mobile ios app using the forceios and not able to bypass the login screen. Here is what I did:

Step 1. 
forceios create

```
    Enter your application type (native, native_swift, react_native, hybrid_remote, or hybrid_local): hybrid_remote
    Enter your application name: bp_mobile
    Enter the output directory for your app (defaults to the current directory): 
    Enter the package name for your app (com.mycompany.my_app): com.bp.mobile
    Enter your organization name (Acme, Inc.): bp
    Enter the start page for your app (only applicable for hybrid_remote apps): bpsbox1-bp.cs10.force.com/BPMobile/BP_Community_Splash
    Enter your Connected App ID (defaults to the sample app's ID): 
    Enter your Connected App Callback URI (defaults to the sample app's URI): 
    Using cordova CLI version 6.0.0 to create the hybrid app.
    Creating a new cordova project.
```

Step 2. cordova platform add ios

Step 3. cordova prepare

Step 4: Open bp_mobile.xcodeproj

Step 5: Add SFDCOAuthLoginHost to plist

[image]

When I open the app on the emulator it wants to login to Salesforce. I don't need authentication enabled for the mobile as authentication is done by community app login page which is a visualforce page. When I look at bootconfig.json:

> ```
> {
>       "remoteAccessConsumerKey": "3MVG9Iu66FKeHhINkB1l7xt7kR8czFcCTUhgoA8Ol2Ltf1eYHOU4SqQRSEitYFDUpqRWcoQ2.dBv_a1Dyu5xa",
>       "oauthRedirectURI": "testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done",
>       "oauthScopes": [
>         "web",
>         "api"
>       ],
>       "isLocal": false,
>       "startPage": "bpsbox1-bp.cs10.force.com/BPMobile/BP_Community_Splash",
>       "errorPage": "error.html",
>       "shouldAuthenticate": true,
>       "attemptOfflineLoad": false
> }
> ```

When I change shouldAuthenticate to false the app fails and throws and exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have the latest version of the mobile sdk:

```
npm install -g forceios
```

Then try with the steps [here](https://ccoenraets.github.io/salesforce-mobile-sdk-tutorial/mobilesdk-hybrid-remote.html).